# Python odata API

Tags: python, odata, devextreme

I'm building a python class that will work with the devextreme odata datastore.

Here is my ODataAPI class:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import load_only

from casservices import db
import models

class ODataAPI:
  def __init__(self, model):
    self.model = model

  def get(self, cfg):
    #"""
    #config options
    #sort = string of "param_name desc" - if desc is missing, sort asc
    #take   = int limit amount of results
    #skip   = int number of items to skip ahead
    #filter = e.g. (substringof('needle',name)) or (role eq 'needle') or (substringof('needle',email)) or (job eq 'needle') or (office eq 'needle')
    #select = csv of entities to return
    #"""

    q = db.session.query(self.model)

    if cfg.get('$select') is not None:
      splt = cfg.get('$select').split(",")
      q.options(load_only(*splt))

    if cfg.get('$filter') is not None:
      NEED CODE HERE TO PARSE $filter

    if cfg.get('$orderby') is not None:
      splt = cfg.get('$orderby').split(" ")
      order_direction = "ASC"
      if len(splt) == 2 and splt[1] == 'desc':
        order_direction = "DESC"
      order_string = "%s.%s %s" % (self.model.__tablename__, splt[0], order_direction)
      q = q.order_by(order_string)

    if cfg.get('$top') is not None:
      q = q.limit(cfg.get('$top'))

    if cfg.get('$skip') is not None:
      q = q.offset(cfg.get('$skip'))

    items = q.all()

    total_items = db.session.query(self.model).count()

    data = {
      "d":{
        "__count": total_items,
        "results": [i.as_dict() for i in items]
        }
    }

    return data
```

how do I parse the following string into something I can use for filtering my set?

The get parameter comes in like this:

```
$filter=(substringof('needle',name)) or (role eq 'needle') or (substringof('needle',email)) or (job eq 'needle') or (office eq 'needle')
```

Comment: My approach is gong to be to parse the $filter using regular expressions into a list and then iterate through the list with flask-sqlalchemy expressions.

Comment: Look at [this](http://tuomur-python-odata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. It may help.

Comment: @Sergey This library is nice, but it is for consuming OData. I wish to build a class that serves OData and responds according to OData's spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across a helpul [OData filter parser](https://github.com/gorilla-co/odata-query) and it works with SQLAlchemy :

Example function I made with Flask-SQLAlchemy:

```
def get_countries(filter, page_number, per_page):
    # OData filter
    query = apply_odata_query(Country.query, filter)
    return paginate(query, page_number, per_page)
```

To call the function, you now just need to pass the filter blah blah blah:

```
countries = get_countries("code eq 'ZWE'", 1, 10)
```

You can find the library and stuff here: https://github.com/gorilla-co/odata-query. Library is also extendable.

Comment: This look promising